# Make awk use bash with the system() command

Tags: bash, shell, awk, command

Is there a way to make awk use bash instead of sh when running system commands using the `system()` call?

I want to use some bash-specific features such as [[ ]] and < > string comparison operators:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {system("if [[ \"porc\" == \"porc\" ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi")}'
sh: [[: not found
```

Comment: Awk is quite a powerful utility. There is nothing so special about the features you mention that `awk` cannot do... eg. here is a simpler way to compare strings without the need for an unnecessary system call and the nuisance quoting. `awk 'BEGIN{ if("abc" > "abcd") {print "yes"} else {print "no"} }` ..(+1 for the question, because is it good to know how to do it, and maybe why not to do it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want bash, you'll either have to patch gawk or call bash directly (the quoting gets a bit hairy):

```
gawk 'BEGIN {
    script="if [[ \"porc\" == \"porc\" ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi"
    system("bash -c '\''" script "'\''")
}'
```

Comment: if those are the only options...

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can do these things by itself:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { if ("A" < "B") print "A < B"; else print "A >= B" }'
A < B
```

It even handles regular expressions:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { if ("thing" ~ "^t") print "t-something"; else print "not t-something" }'
t-something
```

Or, to take your example:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { if ("porc" == "porc") print "yes"; else print "no" }'
yes
```

Having `awk` use `system()` to call an external command is extremely slow and also makes it impossible to get *output* from that command in any useable form in the `awk` program itself.

Comment: As a side note, `gawk` can read the output from the command through `getline`.